# Oracle database column cannot be filtered directly

Tags: sql, oracle, netsuite

I'm working with Netsuite SuiteAnalytics Connect using Netsuite2.com odbc.  I'm seeking to query the transactions table, while filtering to specific transaction statuses.  Netsuite, for whatever reason, requires that you work with the status codes rather than the status descriptions.  I am interested in four status codes including 'B', corresponding to "Pending Fulfillment"

During testing I'm working with a transaction with ID = xxxxx.

I use the alias t for the Transaction table.  Querying the table with t.ID = xxxxx gives a result (5 different transaction lines).

t.STATUS returns 'B'.  TO_CHAR(t.STATUS) returns 'B'. SUBSTR(t.STATUS, 1, 1) returns 'B'. LENGTH(t.STATUS) returns 1.

However, if I use the condition t.ID = xxxxx AND t.STATUS = 'B', or the TO_CHAR or SUBSTR options, then I get nothing returned. t.STATUS LIKE '%B%' works.

How can that possibly be?  Does anyone know what is happening here?  Since I am interested in four different status codes, the LIKE method seems like a bad idea and I'd prefer not to use the fundamentally worse option without knowing the background.

Edit: CASE WHEN t.STATUS = 'B' THEN 'T' ELSE 'F' END AS IS_B returns 'T'

Condition t.STATUS LIKE '%B' works.  t.STATUS LIKE 'B%' does not.  I'm thinking that it is testing against the status 'Sales Order: B' but not actually reporting that when it returns the column.  What a mess.  I'd need to intuit the syntax of that but I'll try and report back.

Comment: It would probably be easier for us if you posted test case. Your answer says "if you are testing during the column descriptions ..." - what are "column descriptions"?

Answer (score 0):

Within `WHERE`, you have to use

```
t.STATUS = 'SalesOrd:B'
```

If you are testing during the column descriptions, you have to use

```
t.STATUS = 'B'
```

Thank you Oracle.